# Carrierwave download throws routing error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, download, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave in rails 3 and am able to upload files and store them properly.  I cannot understand why my download links are not working.

I have a request model that has many request_files.  My uploader is called file, and request_files has file:string.

Here's my download link In my show view:

```
<% @request_files.each do |p| %>
  <p>
  <%= link_to "#{p.file}", p.file_url %>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", p, method: :delete %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The link shows the correct file location when I hover over it, but when I click on it, it leads me to this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/uploads/request_file/file/2/sample_file.PDF"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I would just like the file to open or download.

This is the tutorial I followed to initially set up with carrierwave, but I'm dealing with files, not images [Carrierwave, Rails 4, and Multiple Uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712816/carrierwave-rails-4-and-multiple-uploads)

Here is my rake routes:

```
$ rake routes
             request_files GET    /request_files(.:format)                           request_files#index
                           POST   /request_files(.:format)                           request_files#create
          new_request_file GET    /request_files/new(.:format)                       request_files#new
         edit_request_file GET    /request_files/:id/edit(.:format)                  request_files#edit
              request_file GET    /request_files/:id(.:format)                       request_files#show
                           PUT    /request_files/:id(.:format)                       request_files#update
                           DELETE /request_files/:id(.:format)                       request_files#destroy
                     gages GET    /gages(.:format)                                   gages#index
                           POST   /gages(.:format)                                   gages#create
                  new_gage GET    /gages/new(.:format)                               gages#new
                 edit_gage GET    /gages/:id/edit(.:format)                          gages#edit
                      gage GET    /gages/:id(.:format)                               gages#show
                           PUT    /gages/:id(.:format)                               gages#update
                           DELETE /gages/:id(.:format)                               gages#destroy
                     forem        /forums                                            Forem::Engine
         product_bulletins GET    /product_bulletins(.:format)                       product_bulletins#index
                           POST   /product_bulletins(.:format)                       product_bulletins#create
      new_product_bulletin GET    /product_bulletins/new(.:format)                   product_bulletins#new
     edit_product_bulletin GET    /product_bulletins/:id/edit(.:format)              product_bulletins#edit
          product_bulletin GET    /product_bulletins/:id(.:format)                   product_bulletins#show
                           PUT    /product_bulletins/:id(.:format)                   product_bulletins#update
                           DELETE /product_bulletins/:id(.:format)                   product_bulletins#destroy
                     treqs GET    /treqs(.:format)                                   treqs#index
                           POST   /treqs(.:format)                                   treqs#create
                  new_treq GET    /treqs/new(.:format)                               treqs#new
                 edit_treq GET    /treqs/:id/edit(.:format)                          treqs#edit
                      treq GET    /treqs/:id(.:format)                               treqs#show
                           PUT    /treqs/:id(.:format)                               treqs#update
                           DELETE /treqs/:id(.:format)                               treqs#destroy
    engineering_procedures GET    /engineering_procedures(.:format)                  engineering_procedures#index
                           POST   /engineering_procedures(.:format)                  engineering_procedures#create
 new_engineering_procedure GET    /engineering_procedures/new(.:format)              engineering_procedures#new
edit_engineering_procedure GET    /engineering_procedures/:id/edit(.:format)         engineering_procedures#edit
     engineering_procedure GET    /engineering_procedures/:id(.:format)              engineering_procedures#show
                           PUT    /engineering_procedures/:id(.:format)              engineering_procedures#update
                           DELETE /engineering_procedures/:id(.:format)              engineering_procedures#destroy
      engineering_projects GET    /engineering_projects(.:format)                    engineering_projects#index
                           POST   /engineering_projects(.:format)                    engineering_projects#create
   new_engineering_project GET    /engineering_projects/new(.:format)                engineering_projects#new
  edit_engineering_project GET    /engineering_projects/:id/edit(.:format)           engineering_projects#edit
       engineering_project GET    /engineering_projects/:id(.:format)                engineering_projects#show
                           PUT    /engineering_projects/:id(.:format)                engineering_projects#update
                           DELETE /engineering_projects/:id(.:format)                engineering_projects#destroy
             request_items GET    /request_items(.:format)                           request_items#index
                           POST   /request_items(.:format)                           request_items#create
          new_request_item GET    /request_items/new(.:format)                       request_items#new
         edit_request_item GET    /request_items/:id/edit(.:format)                  request_items#edit
              request_item GET    /request_items/:id(.:format)                       request_items#show
                           PUT    /request_items/:id(.:format)                       request_items#update
                           DELETE /request_items/:id(.:format)                       request_items#destroy
                  requests GET    /requests(.:format)                                requests#index
                           POST   /requests(.:format)                                requests#create
               new_request GET    /requests/new(.:format)                            requests#new
              edit_request GET    /requests/:id/edit(.:format)                       requests#edit
                   request GET    /requests/:id(.:format)                            requests#show
                           PUT    /requests/:id(.:format)                            requests#update
                           DELETE /requests/:id(.:format)                            requests#destroy
               email_lists GET    /email_lists(.:format)                             email_lists#index
                           POST   /email_lists(.:format)                             email_lists#create
            new_email_list GET    /email_lists/new(.:format)                         email_lists#new
           edit_email_list GET    /email_lists/:id/edit(.:format)                    email_lists#edit
                email_list GET    /email_lists/:id(.:format)                         email_lists#show
                           PUT    /email_lists/:id(.:format)                         email_lists#update
                           DELETE /email_lists/:id(.:format)                         email_lists#destroy
                      home GET    /home(.:format)                                    home#index
                    logout GET    /logout(.:format)                                  sessions#destroy
                     login GET    /login(.:format)                                   sessions#new
                           POST   /login(.:format)                                   sessions#create
                           DELETE /logout(.:format)                                  sessions#destroy
               login_index GET    /login/index(.:format)                             login#index
              sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                            sessions#new
           sessions_create GET    /sessions/create(.:format)                         sessions#create
          sessions_destroy GET    /sessions/destroy(.:format)                        sessions#destroy
                     users GET    /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                           POST   /users(.:format)                                   users#create
                  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                               users#new
                 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                          users#edit
                      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#update
                           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                               users#destroy
                home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                              home#index
                      home GET    /home(.:format)                                    home#index
             ecn_revisions GET    /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions(.:format)                  revisions#index
                           POST   /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions(.:format)                  revisions#create
          new_ecn_revision GET    /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions/new(.:format)              revisions#new
         edit_ecn_revision GET    /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions/:id/edit(.:format)         revisions#edit
              ecn_revision GET    /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions/:id(.:format)              revisions#show
                           PUT    /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions/:id(.:format)              revisions#update
                           DELETE /ecns/:ecn_id/revisions/:id(.:format)              revisions#destroy
                      ecns GET    /ecns(.:format)                                    ecns#index
                           POST   /ecns(.:format)                                    ecns#create
                   new_ecn GET    /ecns/new(.:format)                                ecns#new
                  edit_ecn GET    /ecns/:id/edit(.:format)                           ecns#edit
                       ecn GET    /ecns/:id(.:format)                                ecns#show
                           PUT    /ecns/:id(.:format)                                ecns#update
                           DELETE /ecns/:id(.:format)                                ecns#destroy
                 revisions GET    /revisions(.:format)                               revisions#index
                           POST   /revisions(.:format)                               revisions#create
              new_revision GET    /revisions/new(.:format)                           revisions#new
             edit_revision GET    /revisions/:id/edit(.:format)                      revisions#edit
                  revision GET    /revisions/:id(.:format)                           revisions#show
                           PUT    /revisions/:id(.:format)                           revisions#update
                           DELETE /revisions/:id(.:format)                           revisions#destroy
               new_drawing        /drawings/new(.:format)                            drawings#new
             new_e_drawing        /drawings/newe(.:format)                           drawings#new_e_drawing
            new_rd_drawing        /drawings/newrd(.:format)                          drawings#new_rd_drawing
            new_wp_drawing        /drawings/newwp(.:format)                          drawings#new_wp_drawing
         drawing_revisions GET    /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions(.:format)          revisions#index
                           POST   /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions(.:format)          revisions#create
      new_drawing_revision GET    /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions/new(.:format)      revisions#new
     edit_drawing_revision GET    /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions/:id/edit(.:format) revisions#edit
          drawing_revision GET    /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#show
                           PUT    /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#update
                           DELETE /drawings/:drawing_id/revisions/:id(.:format)      revisions#destroy
                  drawings GET    /drawings(.:format)                                drawings#index
                           POST   /drawings(.:format)                                drawings#create
                           GET    /drawings/new(.:format)                            drawings#new
              edit_drawing GET    /drawings/:id/edit(.:format)                       drawings#edit
                   drawing GET    /drawings/:id(.:format)                            drawings#show
                           PUT    /drawings/:id(.:format)                            drawings#update
                           DELETE /drawings/:id(.:format)                            drawings#destroy
                           GET    /home(.:format)                                    home#index
                           POST   /home(.:format)                                    home#create
                  new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                                home#new
                 edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)                           home#edit
                           GET    /home/:id(.:format)                                home#show
                           PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                                home#update
                           DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                                home#destroy
               ecns_submit        /ecns/submit(.:format)                             ecns#submit
                ecns_close        /ecns/close(.:format)                              ecns#close
           ecns_index_open        /ecns/index_open(.:format)                         ecns#index_open
       requests_submit_eng        /requests/submit_eng(.:format)                     requests#submit_eng
       requests_index_open        /requests/index_open(.:format)                     requests#index_open
       requests_submit_mfg        /requests/submit_mfg(.:format)                     requests#submit_mfg
      requests_submit_acct        /requests/submit_acct(.:format)                    requests#submit_acct
     requests_submit_sales        /requests/submit_sales(.:format)                   requests#submit_sales
       requests_submit_sor        /requests/submit_sor(.:format)                     requests#submit_sor
           requests_reject        /requests/reject(.:format)                         requests#reject
        requests_close_sir        /requests/close_sir(.:format)                      requests#close_sir
         requests_download        /requests/download(.:format)                       requests#download
             drawings_view        /drawings/view(.:format)                           drawings#view
             users_sign_in GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                           users#sign_in
                      root        /                                                  sessions#new
```

Comment: have you got the file public/uploads/request_file/file/2/sample_file.PDF ?

Comment: Show your `rake routes`, please.

Comment: The error means your web server didn't find the file so it passed the request on to Rails.  What web server are you using?  Rails shouldn't be seeing this request, so looking at routes and such is irrelevant.

Comment: I've been using chrome

Comment: Chrome is not a web server.

Comment: Oops, I had browser on my mind.  Apache on a Linux machine.