# Save Paperclip image with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, paperclip, sidekiq

I'm trying to save the Paperclip uploaded images throw a Sidekiq worker.
The user select the images into a image[] and passes it to the controller (as params[:image]).

View:

```
<%= file_field_tag "image[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

When I pass it to another var (files), it works in the controller, but when I pass it to the sidekiq_worker, it turns into a hash of strings

Controller:

```
file = params[:image]
SidekiqWorker.perform_async("import_images", file)
```

SidekiqWorker

```
def perform(type, file)
    case type
    when "import_images"
        file.each do |picture|
            puts picture.class
            puts picture.original_filename 
        end
        Product.import_images(file)
        puts "SIDEKIQ_WORKER: IMPORTING IMAGES"
    end
 end
```

How can I pass a hash of image-hashes? Or how can I achieve what I want to do?

After that, the images are processed into a model, but the hash already turned into a string and it does not works.

```
def self.import_images(file)
file.each do |picture|
    @product = Product.where(code: File.basename(picture.original_filename, ".*"))
    if(!@product.nil?)
      @product.update(:image=> picture)
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: sorry, why using sidekiq? you can just do this with carrierwave multiple images upload, there are so many guides about this and you can upload to amazon s3 storage 
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712816/carrierwave-rails-4-and-multiple-uploads

Comment: I'm using Heroku and sometimes the application time's out, deppending on the number of uploaded images. I need this to be in a second plan process
Can I do that with carrierwave? Thank you :)

Comment: I don't really know about that. sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Fabrizio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I just did to make it happen...

After the user uploaded the files, it saves them in a folder and a variable in controller gets the name of each image.

```
when "Import images"
  file = Array.new
  params[:image].each do |picture|
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public/system/products', 'uploaded', picture.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(picture.read)
    end 
    file.push picture.original_filename
  end
  SidekiqWorker.perform_async("import_images", file,0,0)
  redirect_to products_url, notice: "#{t 'controllers.products.images'}"
```

After that, it passes to my sidekiq_worker and passes to my model, where I search for the image and search for the product where the code equals the name of the image. After processing, deletes the file of the uploaded image :)

```
def self.import_images(file)
file.each do |image|
  uploaded = open("public/system/products/uploaded/"+image)
  prd = Product.where(code: File.basename(uploaded, '.*'))
  if !prd.nil?
    prd.update(image: uploaded)
  end
  File.delete("public/system/products/uploaded/"+image)
end
```

end